# Cannot access GoDaddy Appraisal via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.godaddy.com/domain-value-appraisal/appraisal/?domainToCheck=qiyy.com")
```

The intended goal is to have GoDaddy show the appraisal page, which works in regular browser (without logging in, too). However, I receive this webpage:

[image]

What should I do to have it display the following instead?

[image]

Comment: It has anti-crawler measures, try more anti-crawler measures.

Comment: @touero what do you mean?

Comment: This web may be limit about crawler, so you need some other method. Such as, user-agent, cookie or something.